# OpenCV and Java, Reading images

Tags: java, opencv

I want to develop a simple program that can apply a filter to an image using OpenCV. I'm using OpenCV 4.0.1. The code is simple, I think that is correct, but the problem is that I can't even read the image.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    System.out.println("button pressed!");
    System.loadLibrary(Core.NATIVE_LIBRARY_NAME);
    Mat frame = new Mat();
    frame = Imgcodecs.imread("./demo.jpg");
    System.out.println(frame.toString());
    BufferedImage img = bufferedImage(frame);
    JFrame window = new JFrame();
    window.setLayout(new FlowLayout());  
    JLabel lbl = new JLabel();
    lbl.setIcon((Icon) img);
    window.add(lbl);
    window.setVisible(true);
    window.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    Mat frameBN = new Mat();
    System.out.println("Immagine importata, applico un filtro B/N");
    Imgproc.cvtColor(frame, frameBN, Imgproc.COLOR_BGR2GRAY);
    System.out.println("Filtro applicato, salvo immagine");
    Imgcodecs.imwrite("C:\\Users\\Giuseppe Ferrara\\Desktop\\photo-filter\\photo-filter\\bin\\foto\\demoBN.jpg",frame);
    System.out.println("immagine salvata!");

}
```

I've included the following libraries:

```
import java.awt.Image;

import org.opencv.core.Core;
import org.opencv.core.Mat;
import org.opencv.imgcodecs.Imgcodecs;
import org.opencv.imgproc.Imgproc;

import org.opencv.core.*;
import org.opencv.highgui.*;
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.image.*;
```

I will not include the function `bufferedImage` because the problem is not there, indeed after I read the image with `Imgcodecs.imread("./demo.jpg")` when I print that it says that the size is 0 so I've assumed that it can't find the picture, how can I solve?

Comment: Are you able to read the image as a standard `File`?

Comment: Have you checked if the relative path of the image to read, `./demo.jpg`, is correct? The relative path may need to be `../demo.jpg`. Have you tried your code with the absolute path to `demo.jpg`?